# Excel - Count if a value is unique and a different value is greater than 1

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of identifiers, transaction amounts, and number of transactions at that amount. The identifiers repeat if the transaction amount differs, and I need to get a count of those identifiers which appear only once, and where the number of transactions at that amount is equal to one.

So if

- Bob had one transaction at $45.00
- Sally had three transactions at $36.00, one transaction at $22.00, and two transactions at $50.00
- John had one transaction at $25.00 and one transaction at $67.00
- Mark had one transaction at $25.00
- Tom had seven transactions at $23.00

The count would return two.

Comment: What is the formula you are trying to run?  You can edit your question to add this information. Once you do that, someone is more likely to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

To make my answer easier to follow, I've written your example data out as it would appear in Excel, with the column letters and row numbers.

Given the following table:

```
    A        B        C
1   ID       Amount   Count
2   Bob      45       1    
3   Sally    36       3 
4   Sally    22       1 
5   Sally    50       2 
6   John     25       1 
7   John     67       1 
8   Mark     25       1 
9   Tom      23       7
```

This formula will give you a count of rows where the ID appears once and only once in the ID column, and the value in the Count column equals 1.

```
=SUM(IF(IF(C2:C9=1,1,0)+IF(COUNTIF(A2:A9,A2:A9)=1,1,0)=2,1,0))
```

This is an array formula, so once you enter it into an Excel cell, instead of pressing enter, press Ctrl+Shift+Enter.